# Обработка метода OnClick в Unity несколько раз в панели кнопок

Tags: unity3d, onclicklistener

Дорогие гуру Unity game разработчики нужна помощь начинающему ))
В Unity в 2d есть панель из 4 кнопок, по нажатию которых я меняю текст другого компонента. И все работало. Но понадобилось брать текст еще одного компонента и менять его на нужный. Столкнулся что по нажатию на кнопку метод обрабатывает 3 раза. Подскажите люди добрые в чем косяк и как его исправить. За ранее спасибо.

Код:

```
public class PlusPercentWin : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text Name1;
    public Text Amount1;

    public Button button1;
    public Button button2;
    public Button button3;
    public Button button4;
    
    private int basename=100;
    int y = 0;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        button1.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonCallBack1());
        //button2.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonCallBack2()); остальные кнопки по аналогии
        //button3.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonCallBack3());
        //button4.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonCallBack4());
    }

    private void ButtonCallBack1() {
        int b1;
        b1 = int.Parse(Amount1.text.ToString()); // беру из второго объекта значение текста (оно всегда целое число) 
        b1 +=1;
        string str = b1.ToString();
        Amount1.text = str; // возвращаю обработанное значение - в тексте объекта выводит значение +3, вместо +1.
        y++; // для интереса добавил посмотреть что будет в логе
        Debug.Log(y); // в логе выводит y+1 но 3 раза
        basename += 1; 
        Name1.text = basename + " worlrd";     // первый объект - записывает в текст корректное значение +1. в логе тоже выводит корректно но 3 раза.
 
    }
```

Фактически вопрос сводится к тому - как корректно вынять значение из текста - обработать по нажатию кнопки и вернуть обратно обработанный. Т.к. в данном случае что-то идет не так.
Для примера - есть отдельно компонент Текст, компонент Input Field и кнопка - и там все работает гуд. Беру значение из Текст ( Text.GetComponent().text.ToString() ), значение из инпута кнопкой обрабатываю (OnClick) - все четенько. А тут не хочет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`btn.onClick.AddListener(() => met());` как-то криво работаю, сам сталкивался с косяками.

```
// функция события указывается в инспекторе кнопки OnClick
// с указанием аргумета для каждой кнопки 0, 1, 2, 3.
public void PlayerChoise (int index) 
{

}
```

Comment: Спасибо. На будущее буду иметь ввиду. Решил вопрос через фиксапдейт и классовой прайвет переменной. + Я вешаю скрипт на панель и в ней в инспекторе определяю кнопки и как-то хочется через панель все это обрабатывать, а не на каждую кнопку отдельно вешать скрипт.  Вроде работает. Но так до конца и не понимаю почему идет обработка метода 3 раза. Дальше все-равно еще измениться 10 раз с кнопки на объект, префаб или еще че... Буду решать проблемы по мере поступления ))))

Comment: В общем на следующем этапе - все-таки пришел к выводу, что вариант с OnEnable()  и button1.onClick.AddListener(() => ButtonCallBack1()); - просто разрывает мозг ))) и работает крайне не стабильно (то норм, то очень не норм). И моей квалификации не хватает, чтоб его правильно использовать. Но по мне так если ион работает через раз - то дело больше в его корявости )))))
И по факту - отказался от панели и повесил скрипт на каждую кнопку )). С вашим предложением сделать свич по индексу выбора. В целом все ОК работает. ДАльше будем усложнять и искать варианты ;)

Comment: Я писал о том, что бы всем кнопкам указать ссылку на один объект.

Comment: Да я понял. Просто маленько изменились данные и появились доп объекты для каждой кнопки ещё 2 своих и один общий для всех. И ваш ответ натолкнул на мысль )))